# Is there a way to generate static id`s in Vue.Js?

Tags: vue.js, automated-tests

I`m trying to create Automated Testing for an App that is developed in Vue.Js.

Is there a way for Vue.js to generate a static identifier (id, name, etc..) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should be run before building process. More [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/unit-testing.html)

Or you are going to use selenium/something like that?

Comment: Yes, Selenium and Java. :)

Comment: Well in that case just use classes for each element you want test

Comment: with css selectors you can select anything you want

Comment: its generating unique property but you can set your id or class.
<div data-v-61eb39b6 id="your_id" class="your class">
Also you can wrap  the element 'random generated' with your custom element with your class or id

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could set cssLoaders in webpack config to 'extract' css in dev/test/production build and that way it will not hashing your classes